# Which is the correct way to use / initialize Data Binding in Android

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

Inside an activity, we can use Data Binding in two ways:

**Number One**
`val binding : PlainActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.plain_activity)`

**Number Two**
`val binding = PlainActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`
`setContentView(binding.root)`

Both Works, but which one is correct.
Which one we should use ?

**Please guide**

Note: I have read multiple questions and answers related to this area but could not find any valid answer. Hence, posting this question after doing thorough homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both is correct but have a difference.
`DataBindingUtil.setContentView` return binding associated with the generic type `<T>` of the generated binding class. Used for example with `BaseActivity` and multiple inheritors.
`PlainActivityBinding.inflate` return binding associated with `PlainActivity`